# How to add external third party jar in Notes Xpages application?

Tags: java, jar, xpages, lotus-notes

I am Java developer, recently working on Xpages project. we are using Notes 9.0.1. I created Java agent to send email and I want to use some third party jar, something like org.apache.commons.lang3 , end up this issue. how to add third party jar, like commons-lang3-3.4.jar, in my Xpages project?

I tried different ways

1. add jar under /jvm/lib/ext folder, restart DDE.the I can see it in
   my project JRE system libray, but could not import in my Java code.
   Maybe this is the way for server deployment.
2. add jar under /Code/Jars and then DDE generated with new name added in /Webcontent/WEB-INF/lib, but...
3. Add jar directly under /Webcontent/WEB-INF/lib, but not appeared /Code/Jars in Application view
4. add jar under the Java agent Archive folder,  but...

None of them allows me import the package in my Java code.

Anything I did wrong, or is there any good way to add third party jar in XPages project.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to use the jar in an agent or in an xpage or both? Both you need it in jvm/lib/ext in both server and designer. For agent you need to import it when the agent is in edit mode. For xpages the answer below is brilliant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add a JAR to your project by importing it into */Code/JARs*, it should be added so as to be accessible by your build path(2,3). The same is true of your */WebContent/WEB-INF/lib*, but that may not be automatically defined in your version of DDE; for example, Domino Designer 9 has the design elements of */Code/Java* and */Code/JARs*, which didn't previously exist (these are separate folders/paths from */WebContent/WEB-INF/src* or */WebContent/WEB-INF/lib*, either can be in the build path). In either case, if your approach is to have the JAR in your NSF, make sure your build path has the path with your JARs. Separately you could add each JAR individually.

You can get to the Build Path via Project > Properties, then for the part of your build path concerning JARs, go to "libraries":

individual JARs in Project Build Path
[image: individual JARs in Project Build Path]

JAR class path in Build Path (ex- /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib)
[image: JAR class path]

As for the path of using the */jvm/lib/ext* folder approach, I've [covered that in a blog post](http://edm00se.io/xpages/a-quick-note-on-JARs/) and it's important to remember to have the JARs in the appropriate relative path **both on the server and in your Designer**/local path (otherwise your local, DDE, may not pick up the change).(1)

For both, if you keep build automatically turned off, you'll want to make sure you perform another build to see the changes.

As for a Java Agent archive, this should just work and again I'm wondering whether your build automatically setting is enabled/disabled. The */jvm/ext/lib* path ought to work for this as well (shown in my linked blog post).(4) *Note: [as Paul Withers points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493558/how-to-add-external-third-party-jar-in-notes-xpages-application#comment49077089_30493904), importing a JAR to a Java Agent can introduce memory leak issues, making the */jvm/ext/lib/* path preferable.

[image: Java Agent archive inclusion]

Comment: My DDE is version 9 for Notes 9.0.1 and auto build turn on. I think I added the jar in the build path, but will try again. First question how to "import" jar in /Code/jars folder, I only got right click and selected "NEW", no import option. 
tried the last approach add jar in java agent Archive folder. jar is under /jvm/lib/ext and imported into Archive folder but

Comment: How to add image in here? if not allow, I have to answer my own question to add images.

Comment: New = import. And you always can use the navigator view (add it to your Domino perspective)

Comment: @Kevin Don't be afraid to update your question to include the relevant images.

Comment: Works now. My bad. I copy/past the wrong statement. should be "import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;" instead of "import org.apache.commons.lang3;"
one more question, if I just add the jar in my project, my code in Java agent could not import/see it. Is that mean I have to import the same jar  in both /code/jars and Archive folder in Agent subproject?

Comment: @EricMcCormick There is no button or link to update or edit my own quesion.

Comment: I hate to say it, but those typos will get you (and me) every time ;-)

Under the original question, there's an "Edit" link visible to anyone with Edit privileges or yourself, the asker of the original question.

I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: @Kevin Java Agents can't see JARs from the _/Code/JARs_ path; the only location that can be accessible to both XPages and Agents is the _/jvm/lib/ext_ path.

Comment: People have encountered memory leaks with importing jars into Archive folder of agents - they need to be detached to the file system at runtime. Placing it in /jvm/lib/ext would be the method to avoid any memory leaks

Comment: I posted a question the other day about using JARs with Java agents, but it was in regards to running of the Java agents using the IEI tool.  Still waiting for an answer on this if anyone in this thread knows.

Comment: both the issues with java agents not able to see jars and memory leaks have been fixed in later releases of Domino, v12 I think