# how to use google translate text to speech api in xpages

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

i need to translate in input field text. i found this api and how can i use  this in xpage or can i use another way.

gtranslateapi-1.0.jar file

```
Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
String text = translate.translate("Hello!", Language.ENGLISH,    Language.ROMANIAN);
System.out.println(text);
```

https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/

Answer (score 3):

A 1:1 translation of your example into XPages would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:text
        escape="true"
        id="computedField1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            importPackage(com.gtranslate);
            var translate = Translator.getInstance();
            var text = translate.translate("Hello!", Language.ENGLISH, Language.ROMANIAN);
            return text;}]]></xp:this.value> 
    </xp:text>
</xp:view>
```

Add the gtranslateapi-1.0.jar file [to *Code/Jars* in your nsf database or on server into */jvm/lib/ext* folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30493904/2065611).

Comment: many thanks but give error (i looked  mean service unavailable) HTTP JVM: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://translate.google.com.br/translate_a/t?client=t&text=Hello!&hl=en&sl=en&tl=ro&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1
[2350:000E-2728] 10.12.2016 12:36:46   HTTP JVM:        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1481)
[2350:000E-2728] 10.12.2016 12:36:46   HTTP JVM:        at com.gtranslate.utils.WebUtils.source(WebUtils.java:24)

Comment: You should get back status 403 permission error as I do with this example XPage. That's the status Google translator gives back. You have to figure out what Google translater needs as login credentials. The call on XPage/Domino side is working.

Comment: thanks knut, but not working and i found many report about this code the same 503 error. https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/

Comment: i found yandex translate service, i create API key, https://tech.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate-docpage/#codes how can i xml request code block in xpages like this --https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr/translate ? 
key=<API key>
 & text=<text to translate>
 & lang=<translation direction>
 & [format=<text format>]
 & [options=<translation options>]